# jQuery .load() is blocking my script on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm using jQuery `.load()` to include some HTML in my page. The content is shown as expected but all the events bounds to the included HTML aren't working

```
$('.main').empty().load("foo.html");
$(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function(){
    alert('bar');
  });
});
```

It works on desktop but not on mobile. I cannot figure out why... I suppose that the `load()` function is responsible for that, because as soon as I put the HTML content directly in the main page, it works...

Comment: `load()` is an ajax method and is **asynchronous**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/), you will need to leverage the `complete` callback to know when the HTML is finished loading. Because this operation is asynchronous, you need to wait for it to complete before attempting to attach event handlers to DOM elements that have not been loaded yet.

```
$('.main').empty().load("foo.html", function complete() {
  $('select').on('change', function(){
    alert('bar');
  });
});
```

Comment: It worked! Should have read the doc more carefully ;) Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad I could help. :)